# how to take maya animation file in to unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, maya

I have a clip for a character in maya that I want to add character animations to, like jump, run, etc. in Unity , so basically I want to know how to link those animations with the character in unity.

Also please provide me any website to learn basics of unity and games creation like mario etc

Comment: Hi, a quick suggestion would be to read the FAQ. Open-ended questions like this typically won't be answered, but when you formulate a specific problem we would love to help out!

Answer (score 2):

You can drag&drop them inside a folder in your project window of `Unity3D`.

For `Maya` files `.ma` I think you need `Maya` to be installed in the same machine running `Unity3D`. Alternatively you can export them from Maya in `FBX` format.
FBX format can store inside it both clips and rig data.

Answer (score 0):

Typical way do this:

- Export your character in stance pose to FBX file (geometry and bones) - Character.fbx
- Export your character animations to separate FBX files for example idle@Character.fbx, walk@Character.fbx, run@Character.fbx (naming like this is important)(include only bones and animation (but you can also include geometry too))
- Import FBX files in unity, and will add Character to scene - Unity will automatically detect that idle@Character.fbx, walk@Character.fbx, run@Character.fbx is animations of Character (you will able to view all animations by selecting Character in scene and open Animation editor).

Or you can export all (model, animations) as single FBX file and split animations to clips in unity Inspector.

Comment: how we can export all (model, animations) as single FBX file?